# Unable to download 142 or 143

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I upgraded to iOS 8.1 yesterday and can no longer download/install the upgrades. 1.2.0.141 is where I'm stuck. Anyone else having this issue?

Getting such an error:

[image]

Comment: Upgrades have been timing out for me as well, and I've been on iOS 8.1 for a while now. I think it is just the server serving the update timing out at the moment.

Comment: Doesn't seem related to iOS 8 either, I'm still on iOS 7 and I see the same thing.

Comment: Their server is down, thought it's temporary glitch but looks like it's not more severe.

Comment: I pinged the devs in chat, hope they'll look into it soon.

Comment: Yes; I've been running into this with my old iPad running iOS 8.1.

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed now, we had an issue with Xcode 6.1 on our build server. Your next attempt at a download should work, thanks for reporting this!

Comment: Still no luck. I tap to install, I tap "Install," and nothing happens.  (I am on an iPad and I never got the screen that ShadowWizard edited in above.)

Comment: @TedShifrin are you on 8.1? The screen edited above is what I was getting too (the link was literally 404ing, which is fixed now)

Comment: Yup, installed 8.1 two days ago.

Comment: @TedShifrin mind uninstalling the beta, restarting your phone, then trying from the URL again?

Comment: Nothing. No whirling to indicate something is trying to connect/download. Same as I've had for two days.

Comment: @TedShifrin do you have the app-store app installed? Are you using Chrome or Safari?

Comment: I now have downloaded from the app store. I have been using Safari. I can try Chrome ...

Comment: @TedShifrin Weird that you're not getting any error or anything from the beta page, I'd wait until the next beta build is released and try again from there. The App Store version is only a week behind the current beta, though.

Comment: Of course, I discarded the .0.141 version and can no longer get to the URL ... Sigh.

Comment: @TedShifrin check your e-mail from the intro message, or e-mail kasra@stackoverflow.com and i'll resend it :)

Comment: @Kasra what about push notifications that [stopped working](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242973/push-notifications-stopped-working-ios-8-1-stackexchange-1-2-0)? Side effect of fixing this one? Guess less fatal, but still would be nice to get those notifications. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm sorry for the spam of push notifications you just got.

Comment: @Kasra no worry, looks like the android app users got hit harder...