# Push notifications stopped working. iOS 8.1, StackExchange 1.2.0

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I love the StackExchange app, great stuff! Push notifications worked for a few days, then suddenly stopped. Just thought I'd report it here.

iPhone 5s, iOS 8.1, StackExchange 1.2.0.

Comment: Yup, same for the beta channel. No push.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was related to a recent server failover we had recently, as I understand it.

You should now receive many of those push notifications you were missing. Or, at least, should start seeing new push notifications.

Comment: That explains why I'm getting outdated notifications on my Android Device.

Comment: So, [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @ShadowWizard indeed.

Comment: Any chance that this fix caused [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242988/stack-exchange-android-app-keeps-replaying-notifications)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, the failover is the reason for that bug as well.