# Stack Exchange Android app keeps replaying notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, notifications

Version of the app: 1.0.51. (It is up to date at the time of writing according to Google Play.)

This started happening after the network problem that happened earlier this morning. Both my tablet and my phone are popping up notifications for events (comments, and probably edits too) that happened prior to the network issue. I had received notifications for these events *already* and had *already* cleared them before the network issue happened.

The repeated notifications do not show up in the bar displayed at the top of the Stack Exchange sites. In other words, I get notified *again* in Android but do not get notified again on the SE web sites.

Comment: This is probably closely tied in with [Push notifications stopped working. iOS 8.1, StackExchange 1.2.0](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242973).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not a bad hypothesis. It is possible that in trying to solve that problem they caused a problem for people using Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had quite a lot of push notifications queued up for some users, our push notification service went down over the weekend when we were testing out a fail-over to our secondary data-center. This seems to have caused some duplicated push notifications to be sent out, sorry about that. All should be well now.

Comment: The answer is for 2014 and now is 2020 and the problem is still here. It does not bother me but it would be better if you make a dynamic push notification. I mean, as an example, after the user checked the notification on the website, the status going to be updated on the firebase/push notification.

Answer (score 2):

A *possible* workaround if you want to stop the flow of stale notifications but still keep notified about new stuff: an upgrade *may* stop the old notifications.

The version of the app on my phone was a bit behind. After I upgraded it, I stopped getting notifications about old events on my phone. I know the upgrade stopped the flow of stale notifications on my phone because my tablet kept getting the stale notifications.

My tablet was at the latest version. A force close did not fix the issue. I uninstalled and reinstalled. **This did not fix the problem**.

Comment: @GrantWinney I've just updated my answer: turns out that uninstalling and resintalling did not fix it. The flow of stale notifications started again on my table. The upgrade on my phone did stop the notifications... so go figure... Maybe there's some initialization that happened on upgrade that does not happen if one just uninstalls and reinstalls (e.g. old data structures could flushed or updated).

Comment: @GrantWinney Yeah, my tablet was quiet for quite a while too when I thought I had the solution until... hello zombie notification! I'm also wondering if the Android OS version plays a role. My tablet is 4.4.4. My phone is 4.0.3. One difference in the way apps are handled is that in app management in 4.4.4 I get a check box saying "Show notifications". In 4.0.3 I don't have that button. I've fiddled with the box in 4.4.4 and so far no new zombie notifications but I'm not ready to declare victory (because I did declare it too early before).

Comment: Well, the flow of notifications seems to have abated. I don't know whether it is because SE fixed the issue or because of my fiddling with the "Show notifications" check box (which is checked right now).